# $\tau (p) = \tau (q)$ for all normalized traces does not imply $p \sim q$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Could you give an example of a unital simple $C^*$-algebra that $\tau (p) = \tau (q)$ for all normalized traces does not imply $p \sim q$?

Comment: Is that true for $n \times n$ complex matrices?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a simple $C^*$-algebra admits an infinite projection $p$ (ie a projection that is equivalent to a proper subprojection $q$), then it does not carry any tracial trace and in particular it provides an example of the kind you are looking for. Indeed a trace $\tau$ would vanish on the nonzero projection $p-q$, and therefore vanish everywhere by simplicity, as $\{x | \tau(x^*x)=0\}$ is an ideal.

For an explicit example, take the Cuntz algebra $\mathcal{O}_2$.

Comment: I suspect that the OP wanted a simple C*-algebra which has a (necessarily faithful) trace. This is actually quite easy. Take any simple dimension group $G$ with infinitesimals; as a specific example,  $Q^2$ with positive cone given by $0 \cup \{(a,b)| a + b > 0\}$; this has unique trace up to scalar multiple $(a,b) \mapsto a+b$; take as distinguished order unit (1,1)). There exists an AF C*algebra whose ordered K$_0$ group is $G$, and (1/2,-1/2) can be represented as [p-q] in K_0 where $p$ and $q$ are projections, e.g., represented by (1/2,0) - (0,1/2). The trace vanishes on this element.

Comment: @DavidHandelman I do not know what the OP wanted, but your interpretation of the question is indeed imore nteresting. Thanks for the argument.